# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i got this error when i try to upload a file an put it in database using angular4 as front end

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

this is my service

```
upload(fichier) {
            return this._http.post(this._urlbase+'upload',{"file":fichier} ,       
            { headers : new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data' ). append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')}                
        )   .subscribe(response => {
                    this.getAllFichiers();        
                    this.snackBar.open('le fichier est bien ajouté', 'Annuler', {
                        duration: 2000,
                        });
                }, error => {
                    console.error('erreur de l\'ajout ', error);
                })
        }
```

and this is my component.ts

```
upload() {
    let fichier=this.fileInput.nativeElement.files[0];
    console.log(fichier);  
      const formdata=new FormData();
     formdata.append('file',fichier);
     console.log(formdata);
   this.fileManagerService.upload(fichier);}
```

for the backend i'm using spring boot and i added the across origin to allow access :

```
@CrossOrigin(exposedHeaders="Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
```

i try using ARc as a client and that work . but when i want with angular. it's seems not easy ..could somenone help me 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can add : @CrossOrigin("*")

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class Service () {
  // Code
}
```